# local variable named 'selectedData' cannot be declared

Tags: c#

Sorry, I'm a newbie on C#. I'm doing a basic online course and I've mofified the code from one of the examples as I'm trying to write a program which can display a list of movies of a particular genre which titles contain a given string.

I get the following error message when I try to launch the app on a browser:

Compiler Error Message: CS0136: A local variable named 'selectedData' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'selectedData', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

=================================================================

Source Error:

Line 12:         searchGenreS = Request.QueryString["searchGenre"];
Line 13:         searchTitleS = "%" + Request["searchTitle"] + "%";
Line 14:         var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenreS, searchTitleS);
Line 15:
Line 16:     }

## Source File: c:\Users\Charles\Documents\My Web Sites\WebPagesMovies\MoviesCombinedQuery.cshtml    Line: 14

Here is the code:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("WebPagesMovies") ;
var selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies";
var searchTerm = "";
var searchGenreS = "";
var searchTitleS = "";
var selectedData = "";

if((!Request.QueryString["searchGenre"].IsEmpty() ) && (!Request.QueryString["searchTitle"].IsEmpty()  ) )
{
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Genre = @0 AND Title LIKE @1";
    searchGenreS = Request.QueryString["searchGenre"];
    searchTitleS = "%" + Request["searchTitle"] + "%";
    var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenreS, searchTitleS);

}
else
{
  if(!Request.QueryString["searchGenre"].IsEmpty() )
   {
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Genre = @0";
    searchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchGenre"];
   }

  if(!Request.QueryString["searchTitle"].IsEmpty() ) 
   {
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Title LIKE @0";
    searchTerm = "%" + Request["searchTitle"] + "%";
   }

  var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);

}   
 var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Genre", rowsPerPage:3);
```

}

Can anyone help me??

Thanks!!

Cheers!!

Comment: You already have `selectedData` variable declared just before `if` block

Comment: You might have a naming problem, but i think you're going to have a hard time `trying to write a program which can display a list of books` if your looking up books on a databse named `WebPagesMovies` =)

Comment: hahaha ... sorry... I meant MOVIES

Answer (score 2):

You're redeclaring `selectedData` in the `if` and `else` bodies. You don't want to do that - you've already declared the variable earlier. You just need to change those statements into *assignments* to the existing variable. So this:

```
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenreS, searchTitleS);
```

becomes:

```
selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenreS, searchTitleS);
```

And this:

```
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
```

becomes:

```
selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
```

I strongly suspect you'll need to change the type of `selectedData` though - currently it's a string given its initial value - does `db.Query` return a `string` as well? That would seem unlikely to me.

EDIT: As noted, it looks like you just need to decalre `selectedData` like this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> selectedData = null;
```

Comment: Thanks Jon!
You are right,,, it's giving me an error now re conversion 
CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'string'
I've got no idea what the type U should declare to this variable..

Comment: Jon, here is the answer for a TYPE for selectData:

IEnumerable selectedData = null;

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the var from `selectedData` in your branch code

```
var selectedData = "";

if((!Request.QueryString["searchGenre"].IsEmpty() ) && (!Request.QueryString["searchTitle"].IsEmpty()  ) )
{
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Genre = @0 AND Title LIKE @1";
    searchGenreS = Request.QueryString["searchGenre"];
    searchTitleS = "%" + Request["searchTitle"] + "%";
    selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchGenreS, searchTitleS);
}
else
{
    ....
 if(!Request.QueryString["searchTitle"].IsEmpty() ) 
   {
    selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Title LIKE @0";
    searchTerm = "%" + Request["searchTitle"] + "%";
   }

  selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);

}
```

What the current code is doing is instantiating a variable called `selectedData` and setting it to "", and then you try to re-instantiate a variable with the same name as `db.Query...`.

Comment: Thanks... any idea of what type this variable should be declared as??
I've tried STRING but I'm getting this error:
 CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'string'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
```

to

```
 selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, searchTerm);
```

You are redeclaring it, which you don't want/can't do.

Comment: Thanks... any idea of what type this variable should be declared as??
I've tried STRING but I'm getting this error:
 CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' to 'string'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for solving the VAR problem..

As far as how to fix the TYPE for selectData, this did the trick:

IEnumerable selectedData = null;

Cheers!!